# Fetching Directory Count And Reporting It Back

Tags: c#

I am a very basic beginner at C#. I am currently writing a basic speech program in Visual Studio via C#. The below few lines of code is from a section of the program. I know there are many mistakes in the code which I was hoping you guys could point out.

MY OBJECTIVE: What I wanted this section of code to do was when "How many files in my downloads folder?" it would reply back to me "You have `X AMOUNT` of files in your downloads folder". (With `X AMOUNT` being how many files there are in the folder).

```
//THIS IS WHAT I SAY
case ("How many files in my downloads folder?"):
if (false)
{
// this code is unreachable... false will never be true.
//TO FETCH DIRECTORY
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Tahmid\Downloads");
int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
//THE SPEECH PROGRAM TO REPLY BACK HOW MANY FILES IN THE FOLDER
JARVIS.Speak("You have" + dir.Length; + "files in your downloads folder");
}
```

Only problem is, It doesn't work and I don't know why.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions must contain working code, as you want it to work, for us to review it here. For questions regarding specific problems encountered while coding, try Stack Overflow. After your code is working you can edit this question for getting your code reviewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have:

```
int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
//THE SPEECH PROGRAM TO REPLY BACK HOW MANY FILES IN THE FOLDER
JARVIS.Speak("You have" + dir.Length; + "files in your downloads folder");
```

You have the directory count from your call to `dir.GetFiles().Length` assigned to the `count` variable. Therefore, your last line can be:

```
JARVIS.Speak("You have " + count + " files in your downloads folder");
```

`dir.Length` is incorrect, because `dir` is a `DirectoryInfo` object, which has no `Length` property.